# "game" loop in flash virtual pond

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i am having trouble on designing the "game" loop in my flash as3 virtual pond currently  i have the following enter_frame loop. in my "pond" parent container, there will be arbitrary amount of "fish" objects and "food pellet" objects. currently in my loop function when two or more food is placed in near distance of the fish , the fish will not move does anyone know why this happens?

the below code is in my "Fish" class, updatePosition() merely tells the fish to swim around like a fish.

```
public function loop(e:Event):void
        {
            //getDistance(this.x - i.x, this.y - i.y)
            if(foodDroppedArray.length > 0)
            {

                for each (var i:Food in foodDroppedArray)
                {

                    if (getDistance(this.x - i.x, this.y - i.y) < 100)
                    {

                        this.moveToFood(i);

                    }else {
                        updatePosition();
                    }
                }

            }else 
            {
            updatePosition();
            }

        }
```

Comment: This is not really enough to tell what can be the problem. Have you tried debug you code, for example trace something in the conditions (so the function what have to be called is called properly or not)?

Comment: hi, i did not post the whole class for i fear it would be too lengthy.

Comment: on another note, consider renaming that function, loop is a terrible name for a function. try update, handleUpdate (since it's an event handler) or even handleEnterFrame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have here loops through the food array and for each item in that array it will either call 'moveToFood' or 'updatePosition' based on a distance condition.  Presumably these two functions both control motion, and so they may be working against each other, in which case you would only see the last result of the loop being output.

You probably want to break the loop when a suitable bit of food is discovered, and only call updatePosition in the event of no food items matching your condition.

```
if(foodDroppedArray.length > 0)
{
    for each (var i:Food in foodDroppedArray)
    {
         if (getDistance(this.x - i.x, this.y - i.y) < 100)
        {
            this.moveToFood(i);
            return;
        }
    }
    //this only calls when no food matches the condition 
    updatePosition();  
} else {
    updatePosition();
}
```

Comment: tested and it works the fishes will move to each food in sequence and ,yes both the functions control motion of the "Fish" object, by using return; here where would it actually return to? why is break not a choice to use here? pardon me for the questions as im fairly new to these

Comment: return forces the function to exit, whereas break would just step out of the for loop. You want to exit the function because the decision to move towards some food has been made.  If the for loop completes then updatePosition is called as a fall back action.